# How to run testnet node and mainnet node on background at the same time?

Tags: cardano-node

After searching for a while, didn’t find any post regarding this.

I know running node for `testnet` and `mainnet` use different configuring files, and on the cardano developer portal, they are showing the same port. But can I run both `testnet` and mainnet relay node on background (I assume I’d need to change the port number)?
Do I need to make two different cardano-run process?

In that case, it is ok when I run cardano-cli commands just change different network, like `testnet-magic ***`/`–mainnet`? Is the rest command the same?
I currently run the testnet as a systemd service, I can definitely just go ahead and run a `mainnet` node as another service on the background, but I want to ask before head, in case I would messed up the configurations on my server.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you would need two separate `cardano-node` processes, each with their own configuration and their own disk storage directory.

When using `cardano-cli`  you will need to connect to the correct local domain socket for the network you want to connect to.

Eg for mainnet:

```
export CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH=/path/to/mainnet/db/node.socket
cardano-cli ....
```

or for testnet:

```
export CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH=/path/to/testnet/db/node.socket
cardano-cli ....
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
If I do that, every time I switch between `testnet` and `mainnet`, I need to update this socket variable `CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH`, it there a way that it can be done automatically?
I see some others suggest use two different linux accounts, it's essentially the same as changing this socket environment variable to me.

Comment: You can write two trivial bash scripts, with `-mainnet` and `-testnet` in the names and setting the `CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH`.